# Remove Envelope ID Stamping - Sandbox

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to remove the Envelope Id Stamping from dev/sandbox environment?  The following still results in a pdf with the envelope id. I also see no option under Preferences >> etc, etc as other posts mention to remove this.  Not possible in Sandbox?

```
{
  // extra props removed
  envelopeIdStamping : false,
}
```

thanks,

-mike

Comment: The option to switch it off depends on your account type. You can contact DocuSign customer support to have them manually remove it from your account in any environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an admin setting that you can reach out to DocuSign support to have them enable/disable in your account.